# Files contained in sub-module are not copied in the virtualenv

Tags: python, setuptools

My python module "suricate" has three sample datasets stored as csv in it. They are used for testing and for examples. The file structure is like:
    ~/Projects/suricate/data/companydata
Inside companydata I have the files:

```
 __init__.py //which is empty    
 left.csv    
 right.csv    
trainingdata.csv
```

When I install this module on a virtual env, using pip, I have the following file structure in:

```
~/anaconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.7/sites packages/suricate/data/companydata
```

Inside companydata I have the file:
`__init__.py`
The three csv files are missing

What can I do to make sure the virtualenv copies as well the flat csv files?

Expected: Package in Virtual Env folder has the same flat files as in the local folder

Actual Package in Virtual Env folder has all the *.py files but not the *.csv fles

Comment: This might be something to address in setup.py

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsetuptools%5D+package+data

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsetuptools%5D+data+files

Answer (score 0):

you need  modify setup.py and add the packages and file name in it which you require

```
setup(...,
  packages=['mypkg'],
  package_dir={'mypkg': 'src/mypkg'},
  package_data={'mypkg': ['data/*.csv']},
  )`
```

something like this. give relative path to csv file in packages, add packages u required